# how to insert/add last row to sum the column with button?

Tags: c#, gridview, devexpress, xtragrid

how to insert last row to sum the specific column, iam using the devexpress method by showing the footer but it's not what i expected. the first image is my grid view

[image: image1]

the second image is what i want

[image]

so the last row become one with the grid view. 
the code i use is

```
private void hideOrShowTotalToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (hideOrShowTotalToolStripMenuItem.Checked ==true)
        {              
            gridView1.OptionsView.ShowFooter = true;                
            gridView1.Columns["inActive"].Summary.Add(DevExpress.Data.SummaryItemType.Count, "inActive", "{0}");
            gridView1.Columns["code"].Summary.Add(DevExpress.Data.SummaryItemType.Count, "code", "{0}");

        }
        else if (hideOrShowTotalToolStripMenuItem.Checked ==false)
        {
            gridView1.OptionsView.ShowFooter = false;
            gridView1.Columns["inActive"].Summary.Clear();
            gridView1.Columns["code"].Summary.Clear();

        }
    }
```

is there another code to be like the 2nd image?
thanks
(devexpres)

Comment: have you tried setting up a footer?

Comment: nope, as you can see, i only setting `gridView1.OptionsView.ShowFooter = true;` but it not appear at last row of gridview but bottom of gridview